# Changing events in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

We are trying to change the events array in Fullcalendar. We have two buttons that should show different events with an ajax call. The problem is that we can only initialize fullcalendar once. How do we change the events?

```
$('getAllBookings').click(function () {
    calendar('getAllBookings')
});

$('getMyBookings').click(function () {
    calendar('getMyBookings')
});



  var calendar = function (type) {

    var URL = "";

    if (type === "getAllBookings"){
        URL = '/api/Bookings/';
    } 
    else if (type === "getMyBookings") {
        URL = '/api/Bookings/' + sessionStorage.getItem("id");
    }

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  eventSources: [
            {
                url: URL,
                color: 'blue',
                textColor: 'white'
            }
        ],
```

Comment: You can change event source. See official site for more detail. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEventSource

Comment: I agree, you can use two different event source objects and switch between them using the add and remove options.

Comment: Thanks, we figured it out :)

Comment: You can aslo provide CSS class in your event object : one source, different event styles.